# What´s a Symfony worker?

Tags: symfony

I heard talk about "workers" in a refactor of a Symfony application. I have was searching this term (in Google and [Symfony](https://symfony.com) official site) but I found nothing.

***Symfony workers*** exists as a component or part of this framework? 
is a real concept or not?

Comment: can you give us more context?

Comment: Uh, this was several weeks ago and was a video in spanish language. Furthermore, I cannot remember the link. But it had other terms as listeners, bundles, services... I searched for them and no problem here.

Comment: It may be this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline/